# Incompatible operand types double and T for lambda assignment in generic class

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Consider this class:

```
public class TestClass<T> {

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface CheckParam<T> {
        public boolean check(T newParam);
    }

    private CheckParam<T> checkCall;

    public TestClass() {
        checkCall = (newParam) -> someDoubleMethod() == newParam;
        //checkCall = (newParam) -> someLongMethod() == newParam;
    }

    public double someDoubleMethod() {
        return 0;
    }

    public long someLongMethod() {
        return 0L;
    }
}
```

`TestClass` couble be instantiated with `Double` or `Long`.

The compiler gives `Incompatible operand types double and T` for the line:

```
checkCall = (newParam) -> someDoubleMethod() == newParam;
```

How is it possible to assign the `checkCall` field to different lambda types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you cannot compare `double` (primitive type, not `Double`) to a reference (object) type using `==`. Changing your method return types to autoboxed solves the compilation issue (at least for me, but in my case also your first lambda line didn't compile):

```
   public Double someDoubleMethod() {
        return 0.0;
    }

    public Long someLongMethod() {
        return 0L;
    }
```

Edit: However comparing Double/Long instances by `==` is not really a good idea in Java and your comment suggests that you also cannot change the signature. How about changing those lambdas to use `equals` instead?

```
    public TestClass() {
        checkCall = (newParam) -> newParam.equals(someDoubleMethod());
        checkCall = (newParam) -> newParam.equals(someLongMethod());
    }

    public double someDoubleMethod() {
        return 0;
    }

    public long someLongMethod() {
        return 0L;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that someDoubleMethod stems from a third party library with primitve double as return type.

Comment: nice idea, thx. Meanwhile it works also, when casting newParam to the desired type: checkCall = (newParam) -> someDoubleMethod() == (double)newParam;

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create an abstract base class and two implementations - for `Double` and `Long`:

```
public abstract class TestClass<T> {

    @FunctionalInterface
    protected interface CheckParam<T> {
        public boolean check(T newParam);
    }

    private final CheckParam<T> checkCall;

    public TestClass(CheckParam<T> checkCall) {
        this.checkCall = checkCall;
    }
}
```

```
public class TestClassLong extends TestClass<Long> {
    public TestClassLong() {
        // '==' comparison is OK if someLongMethod returns primitive type (long);
        // but if it returns wrapper type (Long), use '.equals()' or '.longValue()'
        super((newParam) -> someLongMethod() == newParam);
    }
}

// and same for Double
//...
```

This way you achieve full type-safety.
Note: equality checks for `double`s have issues, in most cases you should use `double1 - double2 < EPLSILON` instead.